# Why do I have 2 layouts showing simultaneously?

Tags: android

I have multiple Fragments all held within one Activity. On a specific occasion, when I tap the back button while on Fragment B, it takes me back to Fragment A which is correct however it seems as though the layout from the Fragment B is intertwined with the layout from Fragment A. None of the Buttons or EditTexts from Fragment B are functional while on Fragment A but some objects from Fragment B are on top of objects from Fragment A and others are behind.

[image]

Here's the code that I'm using to put each Fragment on the screen as well as my onBackPressed() method:

Code for Fragment A:

```
public void showBetOddsFragment() {

    mOddsFragment = new BetOddsFragment();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("NAME", mObject.getName());
    if(mSelectedBetType.hasGoal()) {
        bundle.putFloat("GOAL", mGoal);
    }
    bundle.putString("INTERVAL", getIntervalDescription());
    bundle.putString("BET_TYPE", mSelectedBetType.getName());
    mOddsFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.contentContainer, mOddsFragment, "BET_ODDS")
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    manager.executePendingTransactions();

}
```

Code for Fragment B:

```
public void showAddFunds(DepositCheckout checkout) {

    String checkoutStr = (new Gson()).toJson(checkout);
    DepositCheckoutFragment fragment = new DepositCheckoutFragment();
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putString("CHECKOUT", checkoutStr);
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.contentContainer, fragment, "DEPOSIT_CHECKOUT")
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    manager.executePendingTransactions();

}
```

Code for onBackPressed():

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBackPressed() - " + getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());

    int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    Utils.hideKeyboard(this);
    hideProgressBar();

    if(count > 1) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please include screenshots what you mean.

Comment: Already on it. Done!

Comment: @EtanMizrahi-Shalom A quick fix is to set a background for a fragment

Comment: @BogdanUstyak, are you talking about doing this within a method like onResume()?

Comment: @BogdanUstyak that is actually an interesting idea, but would be very bad memory wise and does not work in layouts that show more than one fragment at a time, which is one of the main points to use fragments according to https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.

Comment: @EtanMizrahi-Shalom According to info given, you are not adding fragment transaction to backstack, in that case pressing back should finish the activity rather than reversing the last fragment transaction. 
can you please provide detailed code?

Comment: @nikhilbansal, this is so that the user cannot go back to this screen. If they move past this screen, it takes them to a screen that acts as sort of a receipt. If they were able to come back to this screen, then they could possibly take the same action multiple times which would be an issue.

Comment: @BogdanUstyak, I tried setting the background within onResume() and it seems to be working. I'm still not sure that this is a great "solution", however it will do for now until I find out what the actual issue is. By the way, I'm just curious, how would this be bad for memory?